# JPA query with changing where clause

Tags: jpa

I have some entity with number of fields. My client wants to get some selections with variable where clause.

For example at first time it may be

```
"where name='John' and id_version=5"
```

then *name* field may not be using at all

```
"where id_version=5"
```

or may be added some new field

```
"where id_version=5 and sex='male'"
```

What is the best practice to realize it using JPA and Spring repository?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a single best practice to write dynamic queries in JPA. But most of the best practices will use the JPA Criteria API or an alternative (like Querydsl).

If you don't have some unusual requirements, the dynamic generation of JPQL queries with String concatenation isn't a best practice (especially when the parameters are inserted in the query with String concatenation instead of using indexed or named parameters).

Since you're using Spring, [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) is a great library to create JPA repositories. It can be used with the JPA Criteria API or with Querydsl. It may be a bit complex if you only need to write dynamic queries for a single entity, but it becomes very useful when you have this requirement for many entities.

Comment: I use Spring JPA now, but I can't find how to create a dynamicaly changed queries using this framework.

Comment: @wolandec Here is a related blogpost http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data and Querydsl would be a good match for this case. Using the Querydsl enhanced repositories you an express your filters like this

```
repository.findAll(entity.name.eq("John").and(entity.idVersion.eq(5)))

repository.findAll(entity.idVersion.eq(5))

repository.findAll(entity.idVersion.eq(5).and(entity.sex.eq("male")))
```

Here is also a related blogpost http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

This answer is biased, since I am involved with the Querydsl project.

Comment: We had some problems with saving entities with composit primary keys using Querydsl. Actually Querydsl wasn't a problem. The problem lain in Spring Data framework version, which Querydsl ordered for himself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557138/spring-mvc-failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-integer this is the problem.